# TYPO3 Neos - Access Media Management files through TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-flow, neoscms, typoscript2

is it possible to access files uploaded in the media management using typoscript in TYPO3 Neos?
I'm trying to create a site listing all pdfs uploaded by the editors, but I couldn't figure out a way to access these pdfs via typoscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently (state of Neos 1.2 beta) not possible to gather a list of assets with the built-in TypoScript objects / Eel helpers. There are two ways to implement your requirement:

1. Create a plugin that renders the list of PDFs
2. Create a new TypoScript object or Eel helper to fetch a list of assets

A plugin can be created following the guide on the [Neos documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/IntegratorsCookbook/CreatingPlugin.html). If you want to render the list via TypoScript, it's easy to create such a TypoScript object in your own site package:

```
use TYPO3\Flow\Annotations as Flow;

class AssetCollection extends \TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\AbstractTypoScriptObject {

    /**
     * @Flow\Inject
     * @var \TYPO3\Media\Domain\Repository\AssetRepository
     */
    protected $assetRepository;

    public function evaluate() {
        return $this->assetRepository->findAll();
    }

}
```

And then use that new object in TypoScript:

```
prototype(TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org:AssetCollection) {
    @class = 'TYPO3\\NeosDemoTypo3Org\\TypoScriptObjects\\AssetCollection'
}

page.body.assets = TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org:AssetCollection
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll then try to create a TypoScript Object for that.